# Compressing data sent from netty

Tags: java, json, gson, netty

I'm using Netty to implement a client/server application, I'm also using Gson to send data from/to the client in json format and convert it from/to a java POJO.
The problem is that if the data exceeds a certain size the message will be truncated and will not be used in the program. So I'm trying to find a compressed format (better than the json provided by the Gson library) or maybe a way to compress the json string and avoid having the messages truncated.
Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: who truncates the message - the client?

Comment: I guess it's the server (when the message exceeds a certain size) because the client in that case receives 2 messages.

Comment: there is no size limitation what a HTTP server can send. So it's a good idea to find out what is exactly going wrong. The size of the GSON message is not the cause.

Comment: So the problem is coming from Netty? (I'm not using a HTTP server, it's a simple TCP server)

Comment: Most likely the error is caused by how you send the message. There is now way to analyse this without further information.

Comment: @KhalilAouachri Can you help me with database usage in Netty? I want to write a server application that handle's client request, while SERVER retrieves information from database and sends it to the requested client? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If protocol you are using is TCP/IP, you don't have guarantee, that message you send will came in one part. You should put some date to your message, which will allow client to determine if it got whole message (e.g. you can put message length in the begining of the message or some delimiter on the end of the message).

On the client side you should check if whole message came, and if not you should wait for the rest of the message. If you are using netty on the client side, you should put frame decoder in the begining of channel pipeline (e.g. DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder in case of delimiter, LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder in case of length field).